# How to support view other resources data on a resource Show layout

Tags: react-admin

For examples, I have 3 resources that lies on 3 different API endpoints.

`<FooResource />` -> my.api/foo

`<BarResource />` -> my.api/bar

`<BuzResource />` -> my.api/buz

The `<FooResource />` has the correspond Show layout called `<FooResourceShow />`

The `<BarResource />` has the correspond List layout called `<BarResourceList />`

The `<BuzResource />` has the correspond List layout called `<BuzResourceList />`

How can I display `<BarResourceList />` and `<BuzResourceList />` in `<FooResourceShow />`, or in other words, display others resources data in a resource view ?

I tried to import the `BarResourceList` and `BuzResourceList` components into the `FooResourceShow` component, but it doesn't work, because it doesn't know the data to be displayed from `BarResourceList` and `BuzResourceList`

I'm using react-admin 2.2.0

Any solutions on this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show content from various resources on one page, have a look at the demo [Dashboard](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/dashboard/Dashboard.js).

Multiple `dataProvider(GET_LIST,...` that you pass on to a component.